# Error at savefig step: ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create loop for plotting multiple data files.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
import os

pathf1 = r'/home/foo/condt/'
allfiles1 = glob.glob(pathf1 + '/*.csv')
fig1 = plt.figure()



for filee_ in allfiles1:
       dfp = pd.read_csv(filee_, sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
       ax = plt.subplot(111)
       ax.plot(dfp['col3'], dfp['col2'], ls = '-', color='red', marker='x', markersize = 25.0)
       ax.errorbar(dfp['col1'], dfp['col2'], yerr=dfp['PN_6_FLUX_ERR'], ls='None', marker = '.')
       ax.set_xlim((dfp['col1'].min()-0.1*(dfp['col1'].max()-dfp['col1'].min())), ((dfp['col1'].max()+0.1*(dfp['col1'].max()-dfp['col1'].min()))))
       ax.set_ylim((dfp['col2'].min()-dfp['col2'].max()),((dfp['col2'].max()/2.0)+dfp['col2'].max())
       ax.grid()
       plt.xticks(dfp['col1'])
       plt.yticks(dfp['col2'])
       plt.xlabel('col1')
       plt.ylabel('col2')
       plt.title('col1 vs. col2')
       filenamee = ''+ str('%02s' %filee_)+'.png'
       plt.savefig(filenamee, dpi=600)
       plt.clf()

plt.show()
```

When I run the code I am getting this:

> plt.savefig(filenamee, dpi=600)
>
> ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Columns like that in the files,

```
col1           col2              col3
3.39895E-12    52459.7796644
3.62529E-12    52461.7358623
3.67719E-12    52501.6052951
2.26977E-11    56340.081624
3.38851E-11    53574.1580939     53574.1580939
```

When I delete the ticks from code everything going to be a normal... But I need ticks in my graphs. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: what is the result of str('%02s' %filee_)?

Comment: It's giving the names of files. Like this;

/home/foo/filename1.csv
......

/home/foo/filenamen.csv

Comment: are you sure? what is the result of "/home/foo/%02s.csv" %(filename), have you print that/is that possible?

Comment: home/foo//home/foo/filename1.csv.png.csv
home/foo//home/foo/filename2.csv.png.csv
home/foo//home/foo/filename3.csv.png.csv
home/foo//home/foo/filename4.csv.png.csv
.
.
home/foo//home/foo/filenamen.csv.png.csv  like that... That's weird.

Comment: exactly, That's weird ;), try it with ''+ str('%s02' %filee_)+'.png'

Comment: Still same error. :(

Comment: If you report an error, include the full traceback, not only the error itself. Also, we would need to know what `dfp['col1']` and `dfp['col2']` are.

Comment: But, there is a too many .csv files in the directory. But, if you need columns I can write columns for a one file.

Comment: I add more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution. Problem origin is version of `matplotlib` library. Ithink it's kind of bug. For the solve this problem you have to update `matplotlib_venn` library with terminal command at the below.

```
pip install --upgrade matplotlib_venn
```